# Does VPN protect from chrome sniffing

Tags: vpn, chrome

Let's say you browse the web with a VPN connection, but while being signed into your Google account on Chrome.
Google still knows all of your browsing history, correct?

Comment: Not only Google, but perhaps some of your Chrome extensions as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A VPN protects only the transport of the data but does not change the payload in any way which also means no anonymization of payload. If you are signed in to google and surf to a site which uses google analytics are other google service then google still knows who you are.

Comment: but if the VPN service also encrypts the traffic?

Comment: It encrypts the traffic between you and the VPN provider. It doesn't do anything with the traffic beyond that - else the recipient server wouldn't be able to decrypt it.